# How to hide one column based on condition in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Below is my `kendo` grid in this grid I need to hide Case Number column conditionally that means `if(admin == true)` I need to show this column or else I need to hide this column how can I do this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GiIncidentReportList)
.Name("IRGrid").Columns(columns => {
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport).Title("Case Number");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedByName).Title("Created By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedDateTime).Title("Created Date");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedByName).Title("Updated By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedDateTime).Title("Updated Date");
  columns.Template(p => 
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteIncidentReport","IncidentReport",
                     new { incidentReportId = p.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, dlLogId = p.IncidentReport.DL_LogID, incidentType = p.IncidentReport.IT_IncidentType }, 
                     new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this report?')" }).ToHtmlString()

    );
  })
)
```

What I tried

```
if(admin == true){
  var grdView = $('#IRGrid').data('kendoGrid');
  grdView.hideColumn("IncidentReport"); //By Using Columns Name.
}
```

It is working but I want to handle the show and hide at `columns.bound` only instead of using `if` condition.

Comment: where is the value for `admin` coming form? if it is a user claim or in session then you should be able to access this when you are defining the column and then just apply the `.Hidden({some logic here for admin})` property to the column at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Value through @Viewbag and give the condition like this

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GiIncidentReportList)
.Name("IRGrid").Columns(columns => {
 if (@ViewBag.admin == "True")
 {
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport).Title("Case Number");
  }
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedByName).Title("Created By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedDateTime).Title("Created Date");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedByName).Title("Updated By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedDateTime).Title("Updated Date");
  columns.Template(p => 
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteIncidentReport","IncidentReport",
                     new { incidentReportId = p.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, dlLogId = p.IncidentReport.DL_LogID, incidentType = p.IncidentReport.IT_IncidentType }, 
                     new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this report?')" }).ToHtmlString()

    );
  })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your admin property in your model and use **.Hidden(@Model.admin)** property to show hide the column

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GiIncidentReportList)
.Name("IRGrid").Columns(columns => {
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport).Title("Case Number").Hidden(@Model.admin);
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedByName).Title("Created By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedDateTime).Title("Created Date");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedByName).Title("Updated By");
  columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedDateTime).Title("Updated Date");
  columns.Template(p => 
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteIncidentReport","IncidentReport",
                     new { incidentReportId = p.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, dlLogId = p.IncidentReport.DL_LogID, incidentType = p.IncidentReport.IT_IncidentType }, 
                     new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this report?')" }).ToHtmlString()

    );
  })
)
```